# ForeignKey attribute is not valid error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Can you help me?

```
namespace mvcAmerica.Models
{
    public class ArtModels
    {     
        [Key]
        public int idArt { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage="Codigo del Articulo es Requerido")]
        public string co_art { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string des_art { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string modelo { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string referencia { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("LineaModels")]
        public int IdLinea { get; set; }

        public LineaModels Linea { get; set; }
    }

    public class LineaModels
    {        
        [Key]
        public int IdLinea { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage="Indique el Codigo")]
        public string co_lin { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Indique la Descripción")]
        public string des_lin { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Error:

> The ForeignKeyAttribute on property 'IdLinea' on type
>   'mvcAmerica.Models.ArtModels' is not valid. The navigation property
>   'LineaModels' was not found on the dependent type
>   'mvcAmerica.Models.ArtModels'. The Name value should be a valid
>   navigation property name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change this:

```
[ForeignKey("LineaModels")]
public int IdLinea { get; set; }
public LineaModels Linea { get; set; }
```

To this:

```
[ForeignKey("Linea")]
public int IdLinea { get; set; }
public virtual LineaModels Linea { get; set; }
```

It needs to match the property name.

### Edit

I've just created the following application with no problems:

```
    public class ArtModels
    {
        [Key]
        public int idArt { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Codigo del Articulo es Requerido")]
        public string co_art { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string des_art { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string modelo { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string referencia { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Linea")]
        public int IdLinea { get; set; }
        public virtual LineaModels Linea { get; set; }
    }

    public class LineaModels
    {
        [Key]
        public int IdLinea { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Indique el Codigo")]
        public string co_lin { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Indique la Descripción")]
        public string des_lin { get; set; }
    }

    public class AppContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<ArtModels> ArtModelses { get; set; }
        public DbSet<LineaModels> LineaModelses { get; set; }
    }
```

So you must be missing something else?

Comment: I try. but still failed, raise the error 'Multiple identity columns specified for table 'ArtModels'. Only one identity column per table is allowed.'

Comment: Is the same about your edit and my code, but when try ´Update-Database -Force´ raise that error, what's wrong in my EF?

Comment: Have you added a new migration to reflect the change in your model?

Answer (score 1):

You have to change this:

```
  [ForeignKey("LineaModels")]
  public int IdLinea { get; set; }
```

To this:

```
  [ForeignKey("Linea")]
  public int IdLinea { get; set; }
```

The `ForeignKey` name has to be the same as your navigation property (here `Linea`).

Comment: I try. but still failed, raise the error 'Multiple identity columns specified for table 'ArtModels'. Only one identity column per table is allowed.'